# How to make query parameter take two types of inputs in fastapi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I have a function like this,

```
async def predict(static: str = Form(...), file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return something
```

I have two parameters here, static and file and static is a string, file is buffer of uploaded file.

Now, is there a way to assign multiple types to one parameter, i.e., I want to make `file` parameter take either upload file or just string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`Union`** type annotation

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, Form, File
from typing import Union

app = FastAPI()


@app.post(path="/")
async def predict(
        static: str = Form(...),
        file: Union[UploadFile, str] = File(...)
):
    return {
        "received_static": static,
        "received_file": file if isinstance(file, str) else file.filename
    }
```

AFAIK, OpenAPI schema doesn't support this config since it doesn't support *multiple types*. So, better to define multiple parameters to handle things differently. Also, IMHO, it is the better way

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, Form, File

app = FastAPI()


@app.post(path="/")
async def predict(
        static: str = Form(...),
        file: UploadFile = File(None),  # making optional
        file_str: str = Form(None)  # making optional
):
    return {
        "received_static": static,
        "received_file": file.filename if file else None,
        "received_file_str": file_str if file_str else ''
    }
```

Comment: It is a bit silly to produce reasonable looking code that doesn't work. With fastapi it apparently tries to instantiate the parameter, and it doesn't go into Unions before trying to do so. That means you get the dreaded `TypeError: Cannot instantiate typing.Union` error. You should un-fastapi the first example.